# NTFS-3G auto-mount arguments and disk utility

Tags: disk-utility, big-sur, ntfs

I setup NTFS-3G on MacOS Big Sur 11.2 and replaced the default ntfs_mount with NTFS-3G. However, I noticed a problem. Every time I plug in a NTFS I don't see any files show up in finder (but they do show up if I do `ls` in terminal. I found out that if I add the arguments `-olocal -oallow_other -o auto_xattr` to the *ntfs-3g* command then the files show up. Is there a way to automatically mount NTFS drives with these arguments so I don't have to do I manually every time? 
Also, I remember seeing the NTFS format option in disk utility. However, it no longer shows up. Is there a way to fix this as well?